# How to decrease SQL Query from last 30 days until now?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the amount of data for the last 30 days.

```
SELECT ( Now() - interval 1 month ), 
   Count(flightid) AS count 
FROM   flight 
WHERE  flightstatus = 0 
   AND flightvisibility = 1 
   AND flightvaliddate > Now() 
   AND flightvaliddate >= ( Now() - interval 1 month )
```

Right now this is working ok and it's giving me only 1 row that corresponds to the same day of last month.

What I would like is to get the remaining data from each day until now. How can I do this?

I am using MySQL.

Comment: What version of SQL are you working with? You're going to get different answers on different systems.

Comment: @RichBenner I am using MySQL. Edited the question

Comment: You will get data only if the `flightValidate` is greater than `now` because of this condition `AND flightvaliddate > Now() 
   AND flightvaliddate >= ( Now() - interval 1 month ) `. Btw, is `flightvalidate` of `timestamp` datatype?

Comment: @1000111 flightValidDate is of `datetime` datatype. I tried removing `flightValidDate > NOW()` but I still only get one row, and the count also changed.

Comment: Using `COUNT` without `group by` will collapse your result set into a single row.

Comment: Yes and thanks for the clarification with `COUNT` I will remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the `WHERE` clause is wrong.

And since you want day wise data of last thirty days till now then you must have to use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
    DATE(flightvalidate) AS flightValidateDate,
    Count(flightid) AS count
FROM
    flight
WHERE
    flightstatus = 0
    AND flightvisibility = 1
    AND DATE(flightvaliddate) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
GROUP BY flightValidateDate
ORDER BY flightvalidate
```